# Best way to implement Stackoverflow-style reputation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design

I'm implementing a Stackoverflow-like reputation system on my rap lyrics explanation site, [Rap Genius](http://rapgenius.com):

- Good explanation: +10
- Bad explanation: -1
- Have the most explanations on a song: +30

My question is how to implement this. Specifically, I'm trying to decide whether I should create a table of `reputation_events` to aid in reputation re-calculation, or whether I should just recalculate from scratch whenever I need to.

The table of `reputation_events` would have columns for:

- name (e.g., "good_explanation", "bad_explanation")
- awarded_to_id
- awarded_by_id
- awarded_at

Whenever something happens that affects reputation, I insert a corresponding row into `reputation_events`. This makes it easy to recalculate reputation and to generate a human-readable sequence of events that generated a given person's reputation.

On the other hand, any given action could affect multiple user's reputation. E.g., suppose user A overtakes user B on a given song; based on the "Have the most explanations on a song" goal, I would have to remember to delete B's original "has_the_most_explanations" event (or maybe I would add a new event for B?)

Comment: I found this video great: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yn7e0J9m6rE

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I create a "reputation" system similar to StackOverflow using Rails?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5719050/how-can-i-create-a-reputation-system-similar-to-stackoverflow-using-rails)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, I never like data to exist in more than one place.  It sounds like your "reputation_events" table would contain data that can be calculated from other data.  If so, I'd recalculate from scratch, unless the performance impact becomes a real problem.

When you have calculated data stored, you have the possibility that it may not correspond correctly with the base data -- basically a corrupted state.  Why even make it possible if you can avoid it?

Answer (score 1):

I would do a reputation event list for the purpose of recalculation and being able to track down why the total rep value is what it is.

But why have a "name" column, why not just have a value with either a positive or negative int?

This table will get huge, make sure you cache.