# How can I create a "reputation" system similar to StackOverflow using Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have users in my system and I want to create a reputation system where they begin to accumulate points based on a few, simpler inputs:

- The ratings of their reviews
- The number of reviews they have
- The number of followers

I don't need it to be super complex, just functional and believable.  I am seeking help both on the "math" side, but also if there are gems they do pieces of it on the user-interface and data-model side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would take a look at [thumbs_up](https://github.com/bouchard/thumbs_up), I looked into it for a recent project and now wished we had used it instead of a different gem. Seems pretty straightforward.

Comment: GREAT!  I was looking at vote_fu and this looks like it solve some issue, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

While it's not a Rails specific book and more conceptual, I recommend the book 'Building Web Reputation Systems.' [http://www.amazon.com/Building-Reputation-Systems-Randy-Farmer/dp/059615979X/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1303234014&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/059615979X)

Depending on what you're trying to do, lots of planning goes underneath them and the book talks a lot about the process along with other examples from Yahoo and soforth.